# IOS How should I show table with data in Email shown in image

Tags: ios, objective-c, html-email

[image]

I want to share list of records via Email so how should I create table  of records with columns as shown above in image programmatically(Objective C). Is we have to use HTML ? A help would be appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: why can't you create an excel file and share it via email ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thank for fast reply . Here there will be plenty of records no limit so it will be is to create excel file instead of using html ?

Comment: I have no Objective C knowledge, but the final output has to be HTML and inline CSS for it to display in an email client.

Comment: @TedGoas Ya I was also thinking that to.